# Error when trying to share an image

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, share

So I take a screenshot of my activity, then save it to "screenshot.png". When trying to share it via, let's say, Whatsapp, I get an error: "could not send image". Same with gmail, pushbullet and basically all other apps. Therefore, I conclude that the *file* somehow exists, but it is either empty, or messed up... I don't know, honestly.

Here's the code:

**Taking the activity screenshot:**

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

**Saving the screenshot:**

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        String filePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/screenshot.png";
        File f = new File(filePath);
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

**And finally, the sharing itself:**

```
if (id == R.id.action_share){
            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
            saveBitmap(bitmap);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("screenshot.png"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Teilen via"));
        }
```

Where is my error? I don't get any errors in logcat, but I am unable to share the "screenshot".

Comment: Shouldn't you use the same file path for the share uri that you used to save the file?

Comment: I have not? Care enough to help me out?

Comment: @JPMoresmau means to say you saved the file to `getApplicationContext......getPath() / screenshot.png` then you try to add the Uri as `screenshot.png`. If you put the full path in your `Uri.parse` do you still get errors?

Comment: You mean like that? `share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/screenshot.png"));` no, sadly still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should use :

`share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM. Uri.fromFile(new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/screenshot.png"));`

But you would then get *"Permission denied for the attachment"* and you possibly would try but with no luck :(

```
share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

So probably the best way to deal with this issue is to store the captured screenshot in media library and send the file from there.

```
public void share() {
    String filePath=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/screenshot.png";
    String path;
    try {
        path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filePath, "title", null);
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/png");
        share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Teilen via"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it would help!

Comment: THANK YOU! this works perfectly. A small question is there a way to exclude the title and the notification bar when making a screenshot of the activity? (see "taking the activity screenshot")

Comment: Pleasure :) How about View rootView = findViewById(R.id.my_layout); where my_layout is the id set for your root view in layout.xml, but you should use some color or image as its background, because, it won't derive background properties from its root view by not calling getRootView()

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" ....>

Comment: @Mithun, you can format code within comment by embedding them inside tilde character  - this one `